# Access 2010 issues opening Access 2000-2007 database

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I recently upgrades 3 computers to recent HP notebooks, Windows 7 and Office 2010.

However, the company works with several (old) access databases (varying from 2 to 60Mb in size).

Opening these on old machines (XP/Vista, Office 2007) causes no problem. However, on the Win7 notebooks with Office 2010 Access basically crashes ("not responding") when opening. When leaving Access open for a while (anything between 15m to 1h3m0) will eventually open the databases, and the users are able to work in it. But as you might guess, that's just a tiny bit too slow.

CPU wise, when opening the database, 2 of the 4 cores are working. One around 80%, the other at 20%. Rest is idle. No high memory usage either.

The Access databases are on a network share, but making a local copy (on the Desktop for example) didn't change anything.

I installed all available updates.

Edit: problem happens when opening a query or table (not when double clicking/opening the file in itself).

Comment: Is there anything in the windows-error-logs? Is there a startup-form that loads upon opening the DB?

Comment: Only thing I can see is a license check in Event Viewer. No errors at all.

Comment: Have you tried the database on a WinXP with Office 2010? Or Windows 7 with Office 2007? I've had more problems I could associate with Windows 7 than Access 2010.

Comment: No, I haven't. As I'm doing most of it from a remote location (it's for a small npo) I haven't been able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by

```
dpagent.exe
```

The 64bit (32bit process that's running doesn't cause this issue).

It's part of HP protect tools as far as I know. Killing this process resolves the issue...